# Biztalk 2009 Cannot parse message if MSH-7 (Date/Time of Message) is specified to milliseconds

Tags: biztalk, hl7, biztalk-2009

I have a standard bi-directional interface using biztalk 2009 as our interface engine. What is happening is that we are receiving order messages that parse fine except for the fact that they are sending a date time in MSH.7 to milliseconds. The 3 extra numbers cause it to fail with a data type error. If I remove the 3 extra numbers in MSH.7 the message will process fine.

To add a layer of complexity, I found this post: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/biztalkgeneral/thread/d65bf4de-a3dd-47f3-babe-a82bdc260291/ which describes the issue and suggests I can change the MSH schema in order to fix it. I did that, and it did work where I could process the messages in as well as my result message back out, and it seemed all was working fine. However, when attempting to generate an ACK it completely fails. I think there may be a similar issue for batching but I didn't get that far. By changing the MSH schema, the built-in ACK functionality no longer works because the MSH header has an unexpected form (I think).

I am starting to run out of ideas, and thought I would try posting here, as I have found so many answers here in my travels. The weirdest part is that MSH.7 is defined as a string in the MSH schema, so it seems like it shouldn't matter what they pass in this field.

Comment: In HL7 v2.4, MSH7 is actually defined as type **TS** and not a string as you say.  TS is a timestamp and has a specific format:  *YYYY[MM[DD[HHMM[SS[.S[S[S[S]]]]]]]][+/-ZZZZ] ^ <degree of precision>*

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning we are using the HL7 v2.5 MSH header as it is backward compatible with all prior 2.x versions.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the schema you could add code to a transform and remove the offending milliseconds. When dealing with timestamps/dates this happens a lot.